# Cron Job Magento 2.2 fail - Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found in

Tags: magento2.2, magento-cron

**System set up:**

- Magento 2.2
- PHP version 7.1.13 fastcgi with Intl installed
- Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS‬
- Plesk version: 17.0.17

**Elements to the cron set up**

- magento.cron.log
- update.cron.log
- setup.cron.log

Using plesk to schedule cron to the relevant domain on the server

- magento.cron.log = error
- update.cron.log = works
- setup.cron.log = error
- magento.cron.log = error

> PHP Fatal error: Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found in
>   /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on
>   line 111

Some queries suggest removing; from; extension=php_intl.dll

as I cannot directly edit the php.ini (1&1 VPS server) I need to check this will work or any other suggestions?

just to add: setup.cron.log = error. this is without an error notice but I assume that as magento.cron.log is in error it won't work because of that.

Comment: So i actually managed to remove the ; from ;extension=php_intl.dll but now get this error: <br> [Exception] 
Notice: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH - assumed 'MCRYPT_BLOWFISH' in httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php on line 397 


cron:run [--group GROUP] [--bootstrap BOOTSTRAP]

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether you have mcrypt module or not

`php -m | grep mcrypt`

2. If not present, install it

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-mcrypt`

3. Enable the module

`sudo phpenmod mcrypt`

4. Restart Apache and php-fpm

`sudo service apache2 restart`

`sudo service php-fpm restart`

There are chances that it may not work if you have two php installed in the system. One with Apace/php-fpm and one through CLI. In order to be sure that mcrypt is enabled. Creat a file testmcrypt.php in your root and with below code.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Run the file your browser and check if you can see the mcrypt module in the page.